# Can not move out of type which defines the `Drop` trait [E0509]

Tags: rust

I have the following Rust code using [rust-postgres](https://github.com/sfackler/rust-postgres) with the intention of committing a transaction after my struct goes out of scope

```
struct SqlTransaction<'a> {
    connection: &'a Connection,
    transaction: Transaction<'a>,
}

impl<'a> Drop for SqlTransaction<'a> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        let result = self.transaction.commit();
        match result {
            Ok(_) => print!("herp"),
            Error => print!("lol"),

        }
    }
}
```

The compiler complains about the `commit()` line with the following message

```
cannot move out of type `SqlTransaction<'a>`, which defines the `Drop` trait [E0509]at line 12 col 22
```

What is happening and how can I fix that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `Transaction::commit` method [*consumes* the transaction](https://github.com/sfackler/rust-postgres/blob/cdcaec2463380f193659259b029d85c03846cd30/src/lib.rs#L1292-L1296):

```
pub fn commit(self) -> Result<()> {
    self.set_commit();
    self.finish()
}
```

If you *were* able to call `commit`, then the value of `self` would be in some inconsistent state, because what would the value of `self.transaction` be? It's been moved out!

If the type *didn't* implement `Drop`, this wouldn't be a problem, as the compiler would just drop all the other pieces of the struct. However, since it implements `Drop`, then you can never pull apart the struct because then `Drop` could not run! This even applies when you are inside the `Drop` implementation itself.

If you actually needed to do this, you'd have to have `transaction` be some type that you could easily replace. An `Option` is a good choice, as you can use `take` to replace it with a `None`.

---

In the specific case of the `Transaction`, you don't have to do anything special. While a `Transaction` normally rolls back on drop, you can call [`Transaction::set_commit`](http://sfackler.github.io/rust-postgres/doc/v0.10.2/postgres/struct.Transaction.html#method.set_commit) so that it commits on drop.